# Successfully parsed SimpleXMLElement comparison to 'false' returning 'true'

Tags: php, xml, comparison, simplexml

I got a very awkward and specific issue with a simplexml evaluation.

The code:

```
$simplexml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstring);
var_dump($simplexml);
var_dump($simplexml == false); //this comparison
```

var_dump($simplexml) returns the actual structure of my simplexml but the comparison returns 'true' for this specific simplexml, which I can't show the structure because of my contract.
I'm sure that's very specifc issue 'cause I tried other XML strings and the comparison returns 'false'.

```
$simplexml = simplexml_load_string('<a><b>test</b></a>');
var_dump($simplexml); //returns the actual structure
var_dump($simplexml == false); //returns false
```

I solved the problem using the '===' operator, but I'm not satisfied with just making it work. I want to understand why the '==' operator returns true. 
I read about the two operators and the SimpleXMLElement and on my sight it should return 'false' for both operators.
What are the possible reasons for a comparison between a succesfully parsed SimpleXMLElement and the boolean 'false' to return 'true'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

It says that SimpleXML objects created from empty tags evaluate to false. Maybe that's what's going on?

Comment: That's exactly what's going on. I made the tests again and it all made sense now. I just didn't know that a parent tag with no text value that has children tags with/without text values is considered empty. Thanks

Comment: Probably that happens because I got too many levels until the text nodes.

Answer (score 2):

I this this is a better way to do it using boolean casting `(bool)`

```
$simplexml = simplexml_load_string('<a><b>test</b></a>');
var_dump($simplexml); //returns the actual structure
var_dump((bool) $simplexml); // Retuns true
var_dump((bool) $simplexml == false); //returns false
var_dump((bool) $simplexml === false); //returns false
```

Demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/xZtuNG

`===` compares values and type… except with objects, where `===` is only true if both operands are actually the same object! For objects, `==` compares both value (of every attribute) and type, which is what `===` does for every other type.

**EDIT 1**

See Latest Bug on Something similar https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54547

Comment: My XML has too many levels until the text nodes and that made the parent SimpleXMLElement be considered empty, so the conversion would still return `false` causing the comparison to return `true`. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var_dump($simplexml == false); //returns false
```

This is expected behavior and it is explained by data comparison via "loose" data typing.  In PHP, NULL, zero, and boolean FALSE are considered "Falsy" values; everything else is considered "Truthy."  Inside the parentheses, PHP performs an evaluation of the expression.  In this case, PHP evaluates a comparison of the named variable OBJECT and the boolean FALSE.  They are not the same, so the return value from the comparison is FALSE and this is what *var_dump()* prints.

You can use this to your advantage in the if() statement.  Example:

```
$simplexml = SimpleXML_Load_String('<a><b>test</b></a>');
if ($simplexml) { /* process the object */ }
else { /* process the failure to load the XML */ }
```